# Parsing an enumerated array of arrays from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am using Google charts and am trying to switch out the data using javascript.

The data itself is generated on the server from a SQL database. It is then formatted into a string (I can format this however I want) and given to the browser in response to AJAX requests.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to use JSON to create an array that matches the format used by Google charts. This is an example of the way that I would write the variable if it was being generated directly in javascript: `["United States of America", 7.0287],["Canada", 7.3005],["Australia", 6.8945]`

So, this is an array of arrays, and both arrays are enumerated rather than associative. JSON seems to work much better with associative arrays than with enumerated ones.

I've tried using jQuery's parseJSON() function, as well as the JSON2.js library.

```
var sourceData = '["United States of America", 7.0287],["Canada", 7.3005]';
//(the source data is usually pulled by AJAX, but comes in this format)
var resultArray = new Array();

resultArray = JSON.parse(sourceData); //doesn't work

resultArray = $.parseJSON(sourceData); //doesn't work
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your server side technology?

Comment: *"I can format this however I want..."* Then why not make it valid JSON?

Comment: It's always a good idea to qualify _doesn't work_ with some actual result; in your case, a syntax error on the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't an array of arrays, this is:

```
[["United States of America", 7.0287],["Canada", 7.3005],["Australia", 6.8945]]
```

Without the surrounding `[]` it's just a syntax error.

Comment: Well that's easy. Thanks. Any advice on using the JSON2 library vs jQuery to parse JSON?

Comment: And JSON handles enumerated arrays just fine.

Comment: @jgood408 If you're already using jquery (say for your AJAX requests perhaps?) then just use it since it's already there.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are using jquery for your ajax requests.  You can set the `dataType` property to `json` and the result will come back pre-parsed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sourceData = '["United States of America", 7.0287],["Canada", 7.3005]',
    resultArray = JSON.parse("[" + sourceData + "]");
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dUTPN/)

Comment: OP mentioned they had the ability to format the response however they want; the service should be fixed to return a valid response, not hacked on the client.